# Check user input by each char if exists in char array

Tags: c++

```
char Letter[] = { 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T' };

                                if (seg.length().All(Letter.Contains));
```

I'm trying to check if user input being entered have only letters consisted of A,C,G,T

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: The duplicate target works with `string` instead of a char array. I assume that is sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is to check each letter and make sure it's A,C,G,T other wise it will end in re-entering again

Comment: Used iteration and solved it